# Как сделать свой $this->title yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В yii2 есть public $title ($this->title); Где он создан и как создать свой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброй ночи.
В конфигурационном файле задаёте своё значение параметру name

```
return [
  'language' => 'ru',
  'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
  'name' => 'Yii2 Developing'
// остальные настройки
]
```

Comment: Спасибо, наверну я неправильно выразился. Я про view, что бы дать значение именно title через view

Comment: Я не понял про view, о каком view идёт речь. Дополните свой вопрос, чтобы было понятно, что именно Вам надо. Если в представлении для "хлебных крошек", то так и пишите $this->title => 'new_title'

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам требуется изменить заголовок или любой другой мета-тег, Вы можете изменить их прямо в представлении (view) в любом месте:

```
$this->title = 'Your Title';
```

Или можно воспользоваться более расширенным функционалом мета-тегов

```
$this->registerMetaTag([
        'name' => 'description',
        'content' => 'Description of the page...'
    ]);
```

Так же это можно реализовать из контроллеров, но для этого Вам нужно обратиться к приложению

```
public function actionIndex() {
    Yii::$app->view->title = "test";
    Yii::$app->view->registerMetaTag([
        'name' => 'description',
        'content' => 'Description of the page...'
    ]);
    return $this->render("index");
}
```